# How to select the entire row in sql using query

Tags: sql

I have a table name `FooTable` in which I have n columns, but I want to search a particular entire column using query. How can I do that?

For ex:

```
  field1 field2 field3 .................... fieldn
    hey    hi     whats
    hello  bye     go 
     ..     ..     ..
     ..     ..     ..
     n      n       n
  Select *from FooTable
```

I want to search the entire column 3 items, so how should I make the query so that all the columns 3 items are shown?

Comment: people i just need entire field 3 den y should i apply where clause as i need the whole field 3

Comment: can you give us an example of what youre expecting?

Comment: in field3 row whole data i want to fetch

Comment: If the answers given don't give what you're after, please show the variable or row you want from the resulting sql. By "example of what youre expecting" Julien means give a string not an ambiguous request.

Comment: by whole data you mean all the data of the table of column 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question isn't very clear. You might mean this

```
SELECT * FROM FooTable
```

gets all

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM FooTable
```

gets those columns

Comment: SELECT field3 FROM FooTable

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide additional WHERE clause with specific value in that row

example SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = "Hello";

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a variable

```
select @var += field3 from footable
```